# Is this an example of rhetoric?

Tags: rhetoric

I don't know if this is an example of rhetoric.

How has CVS changed over the past few years?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It may or may not be *rhetoric*; it may or may not be a *rhetorical question*. In either case, it is not clear what you are asking. Can you provide the context of the sentence (whitepaper? exam question?) and explain what *you* think the answer is? I encourage to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/) for additional guidance on how to ask answerable questions.

Comment: Please start by looking up [*rhetoric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking about a rhetorical question.  Rhetoric by itself is a much broader category.

Whether the given question is a rhetorical question or not is impossible to say without more context.  Does the speaker/author ask the question and then immediately proceed to answer it without waiting for or expecting an answer from another party?  If so, then it was a rhetorical question.